# How to set sessions timeout in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, session-cookies, django-sessions

I want to implement login and logout session in my website through which after a set of time the session should expire automatically. And if user logged in then the user could not go back.

Comment: There is already existing contrib app in django itself https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/. You don't need to implement anything

Comment: but in my case there is no session time out and if user logged in he/she can easily go back after logged out.

Comment: There is settings param for setting timeout. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE. By default it set to 2 weeks. you can change it to any period you want

Comment: how to change that period ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `settings.py` set https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE.

For example if you want time out to be one hour

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600 # one hour in seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

To **"settings.py"**, set [**SESSION_COOKIE_AGE**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) which is **1209600 seconds(2 weeks)** by default and [**SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) which is **"False"** by default  as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 180 # 3 minutes. "1209600(2 weeks)" by default

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True # "False" by default
```

If [**SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) is **"True"**, users are logged out if **inactive**.

If [**SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) is **"False"**, users are logged out whether **active** or **inactive**.